# Multiple ways of using custom Gradle plugins in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

With reference to the [Gradle docs section 59.2](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) I have created a simple plugin to illustrate various (seemingly working) ways to use a custom Gradle plugin's DSL exposed via plugin extensions. For example the following plugin definition and class

```
class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // Add the 'greeting' extension object
        project.extensions.create("greeting", GreetingPluginExtension)
        // Add a task that uses the configuration
        project.task('hello') << {
            println project.greeting.message
        }
    }
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    def String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
}
```

can be called in four ways

- `greeting.message 'Hi from Gradle with dot'`
- `greeting.message = 'Hi from Gradle with dot and assigment'`
- `greeting { message 'Hi from Gradle with block' }`
- `greeting { message = 'Hi from Gradle with block with assignment' }`

what is the correct and recommended way? Are there implications of using one way over another? In that simple example they all appear to work

Comment: All the ways are good, they're just evaluated in a different way (via different mechanisms). In some situations passing a closure wrapping the configuration is more convenient and better visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Opal said, all 4 ways are good, depending on your requirements in readability. If you have more things to configure than just the message, then the configuration block using a closure may be more convenient.

There's also a difference between using the assignment operator and omitting it: when using the assignment operator, you are explicitly setting a property, while omitting it means calling a method with that name. In that case, I prefer using the assignment operator.

You can have a look here: http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters